# how can i solve timeout problem in C code

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a text from a file by a file descriptor and `BUFFER_SIZE` given by the user, in my code however `BUFFER_SIZE` size be, my function reads one line and returns it and the reminder for read will be stored in a static variable for the next call.
basically, my function is working but in some tests, it gives me a timeout
I tried to solve the problem but I did not find the case

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

static size_t   ft_gnl_strlen(char *ptr, char sep)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (ptr && ptr[i] && ptr[i] != sep)
        i++;
    if (ptr && ptr[i] == '\n')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_gnl_strchr(const char *p, char ch)
{
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        if (*p == (char)ch)
            return ((char *)p);
        p++;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

static void ft_gnl_change_reminder(char *helper)
{
    char    ptr[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    size_t  i;
    size_t  j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (helper[i] != '\n' && helper[i])
        i++;
    if (helper[i] == '\n' && helper[i])
        i++;
    while (helper[i])
        ptr[j++] = helper[i++];
    while (j <= BUFFER_SIZE)
        ptr[j++] = '\0';
    i = -1;
    while (ptr[++i])
        helper[i] = ptr[i];
    while (i <= BUFFER_SIZE)
        helper[i++] = '\0';
}

static char *ft_gnl_join(char *ptr, char *helper)
{
    char    *newptr;
    size_t  i;
    size_t  ptrlen;

    if (!ptr && !helper)
        return (free(ptr), NULL);
    i = -1;
    ptrlen = ft_gnl_strlen(ptr, '\0');
    newptr = (char *)malloc(ptrlen + ft_gnl_strlen(helper, '\n') + 1);
    if (!newptr)
        return (free(ptr), NULL);
    while (ptr && ptr[++i])
        newptr[i] = ptr[i];
    i = 0;
    while (helper && helper[i] != '\n' && helper[i])
        newptr[ptrlen++] = helper[i++];
    if (helper && helper[i] && helper[i] == '\n')
        newptr[ptrlen++] = '\n';
    newptr[ptrlen] = '\0';
    return (free(ptr), ft_gnl_change_reminder(helper), newptr);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char helper[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char        *ptr;

    if (fd < 0 || read(fd, helper, 0) < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE < 1)
        return (helper[0] = '\0', NULL);
    ptr = (char *)malloc(1);
    if (!ptr)
        return (NULL);
    ptr[0] = '\0';
    if (ft_gnl_strlen(helper, '\0'))
    {
        ptr = ft_gnl_join(ptr, helper);
        if (!ptr)
            return (NULL);
    }
    while (!ft_gnl_strchr(ptr, '\n') && read(fd, helper, BUFFER_SIZE))
    {
        helper[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';
        ptr = ft_gnl_join(ptr, helper);
        if (!ptr)
            return (NULL);
    }
    if (ptr[0] == '\0')
        return (free(ptr), NULL);
    return (ptr);
}
```

I tested my code with a tester named **Paco** and it give me that :

BUFFER_SIZE: 10

giant_line.txt      : 1.OK 2.OK 3_LEAKS.OK 4.KO Timeout

giant_line_nl.txt   : 1.OK 2.OK 3.OK 4_LEAKS.OK 5.KO Timeout

```
Errors found:
Error in test 4: get_next_line(5: "giant_line.txt"):
malloc protection check for 594th malloc:
     in _add_malloc malloc_mock.c:29:8
     in malloc malloc_mock.c:75:10
  -> in ft_gnl_join get_next_line.c:71:9
     in get_next_line get_next_line.c:105:7
     in null_check_gnl file_utils.c:116:7
     in main tester.c:173:3

Error in test 5: get_next_line(5: "giant_line_nl.txt"):
malloc protection check for 597th malloc:
     in _add_malloc malloc_mock.c:29:8
     in malloc malloc_mock.c:75:10
  -> in ft_gnl_join get_next_line.c:71:9
     in get_next_line get_next_line.c:105:7
     in null_check_gnl file_utils.c:116:7
     in main tester.c:181:3
```

Comment: I would work on fixing the memory errors first, they may be causing the tests to fail.

Comment: `return (free(ptr), ft_gnl_change_reminder(helper), newptr);` if you program this way, you will never get out of trouble. static variables are a very bad idea - avoid. Generally horrible code - I would suggest rewriting it from scratch, but first, you need to draw the algorithm on the sheet of paper

Comment: @RetiredNinja where is the memory errors , everything is fine , no leaks no buffers over flow

Comment: Read the bottom half of your question. "3_LEAKS" "4_LEAKS" "Errors found:..."

Comment: no that mean ther is no leaks found

Comment: And I suppose "Errors found:" means no errors?